# Place items in center and lower right corner of a fullscreen flexbox?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, flexbox

On my site, I've created a flex box which fills the whole window. It has a width of 100% and a height of 100vh. I've placed a text and a button in the center of it. Now I want to add a footer to the page. If I place the footer under the div (flexbox) It'll only show up if I scroll down a little bit. So can I create another div inside the flexbox which will place it's items in the lower right corner of the page?

Comment: can you add your code to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It's a rails project. So jsfiddle won't show i correctly.

Comment: show real project. is it online?

Comment: No. It's running on my local machine.

Comment: then we can't help you we need too see the code and visual example

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is hard to help but maybe try in the css `float:right`